# preg_replace links text with

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm modifying a php page that has messages.

Message is like

```
Welcome to our page bla bla bla <a href="link.php">Link content</a>
```

I need to replace Link content with

```
<img src="constant.png"/>
```

How do I do that?

PS. Do u know any good tutorials about regular expressions?

thanks

Comment: are you sure what you actually want to do?

Comment: do you want to replace the whole `anchor` tag

Comment: Altering HTML with regexs can be difficult, as there could be attributes in the <a> tags, inconsistencies in whitespaces, etc that you would have to take into account. It can certainly be done but it might not be the ideal solution. What about altering the links using Javascript? it's easier to grab all <a> elements and modify them as you see fit.

Comment: Use the search box (top right of the page). There are at least hundreds of questions just like this one.

Comment: As already mentioned, it's kinda messy with preg_replace, because of nesting an so on. I would use DOMNode to do this kind of job.

Comment: You're the winner of the first FAQ question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no other tags enclosing "Link content", you can do this in `bash`:

```
sed -r 's@<a href="[^"]+">[^<]*</a>@<img src="constant.png"/>@g'
```

or even better if you don't need to access the value in the attribute `href`:

```
sed -r 's@<a[^>]*>[^<]*</a>@<img src="constant.png"/>@g'
```

Comment: What if the anchor has other attributes such as 'title' or 'class'?

Comment: Oh, yah, actually you can just skip anything, since you don't need the value inside the href attribute anyway.